# I can not trace when a html element has been generated

Tags: html, templates, dom, tags

There are two elements(table and header) that I can not see when they have been generated in my code.I checked all the .js files, all the templates but there is nothing 'suspicious'.Can you tell me how could I trace the moment when the element has been generated and eventualy from which file?

I used the Fiddler2 to see the order that the things are being loaded and I can see all the .js files and .css files, I checked them all but nothing.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the code :).

Comment: I was just wondering if there is a way after selecting the element(lets say <h1></h1> a specific one on the html-F12) to see which file has generated it.Something like stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Sure - go to your dev tools, go to the console, and run something like this:

```
$("body").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() { debugger; });
```

You can monkey with the selector (also assumed jQuery was available) to get it down to the specific item you want.  That should give you a stack trace as well.

Let us know if this works!

Comment: After entering that in the console a Object is being returned but how do I procceed from then on? I have all the elements that I want to trace but how do I call the "calling stack trace" of a particular element that has no id and nothing.

Comment: I was making the assumption that these elements showed up after body load :)  If you want to accomplish the same thing, you can actually embed code like this into your source (just until you find the culprit).  I would find a selector that's narrowed down to the element you're trying to find.  Whatever container has the table and header, use that selector with the above statement in your source.